# Check if there's a lesser/greater sign in string

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm simply trying to check for a ">" and a "<" in the string but I get an

> SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^\<#+([0-9]{18}+>)$/: Nothing to repeat

error...

I know the problems are the lesser/greater signs in the match function but I don't know how to replace them with a letter code thing...

```
string.match("^<#+([0-9]{18}+>)$")
```

Edit: Turns out there was an extra "+" that wasnt needed.
Correct Version:

```
string.match("^<#+([0-9]{18}>)$")
```

Comment: The error should be that `+` after the `}`

Comment: Okay sorry for no clarification... Im trying to match the string to something like this
    <#123456789123456789>

Comment: That worked for me... Thanks...

Comment: @DanielJenßen Beware that Discord devs have said that snowflakes (those IDs between the `<#` and `>`) should not be checked against any particular length since they can change. You ought to ditch the length requirement on that

Comment: Thanks for the advice...

Comment: Keep in mind that not all Discord ID snowflakes are 18 digits, nor do they have to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the `+` sign after the braces is the issue here.

---

If you want to have **exactly 18 digits**, this should do the trick:

`^<#+([0-9]{18}>)$`

If you are instead looking for a **minimum of 18 digits**, this will work:

`^<#+([0-9]{18,}>)$`

Comment: Glad I could help you get an answer. Might want to also remove the other `+` which is wrong too.

Comment: I find that this site is excellent for debugging RegExes: https://www.regexr.com/